# Difference between All-to-All Reduction and All-Reduce in MPI

Tags: mpi, communication

Trying to figure out the difference between All-to-All Reduction and All-Reduce in open MPI. From my understanding All-to-One Reduction takes a piece `m` (integer, array, etc..) from all processes and combines all the pieces together with an operator (min, max, sum, etc..) and stores it in the selected process. From this i assume that All-to-All Reduction is the same but the product is stored in all the processes instead of just one. From [this](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) document it seems like All-Reduce is basically doing the same as All-to-All Reduction, is this right or am i getting it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *all-reduce* (`MPI_Allreduce`) is a combined *reduction* and *broadcast* (`MPI_Reduce`, `MPI_Bcast`). They might have called it `MPI_Reduce_Bcast`. It is important to note that a MPI reduction does not do any global reduction. So if have 10 numbers each on 5 processes, after a `MPI_Reduce` one process has 10 numbers. After `MPI_Allreduce`, all 5 processes have the same 10 numbers.

In contrast, the *all-to-all reduction* performs a *reduction* and *scatter*, hence it is called `MPI_Reduce_scatter[_block]`. So if you have 10 numbers each on 5 processes, after a `MPI_Reduce_scatter_block`, the 5 processes have 2 numbers each. Note that MPI doesn't itself use the terminology *all-to-all reduction*, probably due to the misleading ambiguity.